# vba application.unique works in one environment whilst not in the other

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following line of vba code in a subroutine:

```
filter_values_Lrow = Range("C"& Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
contracts_products = Application.transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(Range("B2:B"&filter_values_Lrow)).
```

This code works well in the "normal environment", whilst when I run this code on my virtual machine it produces an 438 error: Object doesn't support this property or method. Does anyone know why this could be the case? The excel file is able to be opened and other mutations on that file are possible.

Kind regards.

Comment: your example code has issues like missing brackets, etc.   You indicated `unique` is the problem... so if you remove all the other code (like 'transpose') do you still get the same error?  Check out how to create a [mcve]. Also more information about the virtual machine may be helpful. Which "mutations" are you referring to?

Comment: `Unique` was added in a late Office version (Microsoft 365/ Excel 2021). Which version do you use on your normal environment and which one do you use in your virtual machine? If they are different there is a high chance that `Unique` does not exist in the old version.